# Operation between raster using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator

I create two raster using QGIS Interpolation tools starting from two vector (Point): one with an accessibility index( between 1 and 5) for each point  and one with population (number of people) for each point.
I need to combine the two raster to have the % of population for each index value.
I've never worked with raster in QGIS.

Comment: You should clarify a bit more what the vectors have as values. E.g. "population for each point" - is this a number of people or percent of the whole population? Since later you are looking for "% of population for each index value".

Comment: I think you can do this by polygonizing the accessibility raster (you might need to categorize it first), then use the `zonal statistics` tool to calculate the population in each accessibility zone polygon. The answer to @miln40's question will determine which statistic to calculate (sum vs mean).

Comment: Number of people for each point, accessibility index between 1 and 5. I Need % of people for each index.

Comment: @csk you say polygonize  the raster but it mean convert again to vector. Maybe it's not necessary since I start from a vector.

Comment: That was just a suggestion. You really haven't provided enough information about your starting data for a complete answer. If you still need help, please use the [edit] button to clarify your question.

Comment: I already edit the question. Hope is more clear.

Comment: @miln40, csk any tips?

Comment: using zonal statistic tool I'm not able to have the % for each index but only some statistics